# href not working on table td's but it works on ul li's

Tags: php, html, css

I am in bit of a situation here.
When I change the tr to ul and td to li then the links work but in the table it links does not work.
The links are fetched by permalink and the code after that

```
if (sizeof($allMessages)>0)
    {
      foreach($allMessages as $message){?>
            <tr>
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>?candidate-page=mailbox-readmail&messageId=<?php echo esc_html__($message['id'],'nokri') ?>" class="list-inline"><?php if(in_array("UNREAD", $message['labelIds'])){ ?><b class="list-inline">
                <td class="posted-job-title"><?php echo esc_html__($message['email'] , 'nokri' ); ?></td>
                <td class="posted-job-status"><?php echo esc_html__( $message['subject'], 'nokri' ); ?></td>
                <td style="margin-right: 148px;" class="posted-job-status"><?php echo esc_html__( $message['from'], 'nokri' ); ?></td>

                </b>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <td class="posted-job-title"><?php echo esc_html__($message['email'] , 'nokri' );?></td>
                <td class="posted-job-status"><?php echo esc_html__( $message['subject'], 'nokri' ); ?></td>
                <td style="margin-right: 147px;" class="posted-job-status"><?php echo esc_html__( $message['from'], 'nokri' ); ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                </a>
                <td>
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>?candidate-page=mailbox-inbox&messageId=<?php echo esc_html__($message['id'],'nokri') ?>&delete=true" class="list-inline"><li class="posted-job-action"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
      <?php
```

Comment: That's because wrapping a `<td>` in a `<a>` is invalid HTML

Comment: A `tr` followed by an `a` is not valid HTML.

Comment: is there any workaround this

Comment: If you want a whole table row to be clickable, then use a JavaScript click handler for that. Making that click “link to” somewhere else can be done by assigning the new URL to `location.href`. And in general, you should go read up on some HTML basics, before you proceed - that code is a mess in more than one regard.

Comment: Sure, use valid markup.  It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how a table structure should flow. Right now, a simplified version of your table structure looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <a href="/content">
  <td>Content here</td>
 </a>
</tr>
```

The `<a>` tag is inside of the TR element.

Have you tried putting the `<a>` tag in the TD element?

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="/content">Content here</a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

The `<a>` tag is now inside of the table cell its self, and content should flow nicely.

Also look for any syntax errors.
Best of luck!