# Highlight every second li row with some background color

Tags: css

I want am trying to change the background color of every second li row like the background color of the ul which has the headings. 
The first row should have default color and then second row should have a custom color and so on.

I tried setting nth-of-child(even) to li but it doesn't work as expected because it counts the individual li element and not the whole row

http://jsfiddle.net/roznfxjL/

```css
.widthh {
  width: 100%;
}

.cont {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.email {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.subject {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.from {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.action {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="widthh cont">
  <li class="email">
    Email
  <li class="subject">
    Subject
  <li class="from">
    From
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Action
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="widthh">
  <li class="email">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <li class="subject">
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  <li class="from">
    Devid Jon
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Delete
  </li>
  <li class="email">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <li class="subject">
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  <li class="from">
    Devid Jon
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Delete
  </li>
  <li class="email">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <li class="subject">
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  <li class="from">
    Devid Jon
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Delete
  </li>
  <li class="email">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <li class="subject">
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  <li class="from">
    Devid Jon
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Delete
  </li>
  <li class="email">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <li class="subject">
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  <li class="from">
    Devid Jon
  </li>
  <li class="action">
    Delete
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there is no `nth-of-child`, do you mean `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`? Which did you use?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `ul` and `li` instead of a table. I am not saying it cant be done the way you are doing it, but it would be simpler and more semantic to use a table

Comment: yea I am not using table because table is not working  links <a href  refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185239/href-not-working-on-table-tds-but-it-works-on-ul-lis

Answer (score 0):

**Repetitive pattern.**
Your pattern could be describe like that :
Four elements with no background, then four elements with background, and so on.
It means that it repeats itself *every eight elements*.

You can use `nth-child()` for that

```
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+5), /* 5, 13, 21 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+6), /* 6, 14, 22 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+7), /* 7, 15, 23 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+8) /* 8, 16, 24 */ { 
  background: red;
}
```

**With your exemple :**

```css
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+5), /* 5, 13, 21 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+6), /* 6, 14, 22 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+7), /* 7, 15, 23 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+8) /* 8, 16, 24 */ {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- By cupusasa -->
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
       .widthh{
        width: 100%;
       }
        .cont{
          background: #f2f2f2;
        }
  .email {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   width: 35%;
   margin-right: 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
  .subject {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 15%;
   vertical-align: top;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .from {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 10%;
   vertical-align: top;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .action {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 10%;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="widthh cont">
<li class="email">
Email
<li class="subject">
Subject
<li class="from">
From
</li>
<li class="action">
Action
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="widthh">
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li><li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want it to look more like row (same height of the li), you could use some flex.

But then, you will need to adjust the width of your columns to match your first list.

```css
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+5), /* 5, 13, 21 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+6), /* 6, 14, 22 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+7), /* 7, 15, 23 */
.widthh + .widthh li:nth-child(8n+8) /* 8, 16, 24 */ {
  background: red;
}

.widthh + .widthh { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.widthh + .widthh li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- By cupusasa -->
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
       .widthh{
        width: 100%;
       }
        .cont{
          background: #f2f2f2;
        }
  .email {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   width: 35%;
   margin-right: 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
  .subject {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 15%;
   vertical-align: top;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .from {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 10%;
   vertical-align: top;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .action {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style: none;
   width: 10%;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="widthh cont">
<li class="email">
Email
<li class="subject">
Subject
<li class="from">
From
</li>
<li class="action">
Action
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="widthh">
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
<li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li><li class="email">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<li class="subject">
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
<li class="from">
Devid Jon
</li>
<li class="action">
Delete
</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```